# Reverting object property changes in php

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a bunch of Doctrine php objects and I'm calling things like

```
$myObj = $query->execute()->getFirst();
$myObj->setName('a new name');
$myObj->setAge('40');
$myObj->save();
```

etc...
etc...

And at some point, if encounter an error, I'd like to revert all those property changes since I've already called the save() function and that propagates the new properties to the database.

I'd like to come up with a way to store the old value of the object as well as which method to call to revert it. Something like:

```
$undoCollection = array();
$undoObject = array();
$undoObject['revertFunction'] = $myObj->setName;
$undoObject['revertValue'] = 18;
array_push($undoCollection,$undoObject)
```

So that later on, if something goes wrong, I can loop through the $undoCollection:

```
foreach($undoCollection as $undoObj)
{
    $undoObj['revertFunction']($undoObj['revertValue']);
}
```

Is this something that's possible in PHP? Or is there something else that can provide that functionality?

Comment: If this is a requirement then you should be using transactions on your database connections... then you can just call a rollback. If this won't work for you see the  Zend_Db_Table_Abstract in the zend_framework 1.x version to see an example of what you are try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [transactions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/transactions.html). E.g.:

```
$myObj = $query->fetchOne();

if ($myObj)
{
  $conn = $myObj->getTable()->getConnection();

  try
  {
    $conn->beginTransaction();

    $myObj->setName('Asd')->save();

    // do other stuff...

    // if an exception is thrown before calling commit
    // nothing in this try block will be saved 
    $conn->commit();
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    $conn->rollback();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! if I create a new object before calling commit(), can I retrieve the new object's id? Or will it not exist until I press commit()?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you don't have an ID until the transaction committed. You should bound objects together by reference instead and doctrine will do the rest. So use relations... e.g. `$group = new Group(); $group->setName('group_1')->save(); $user = new User();  $user->getGroups()->add($group); $user->save();` [docs here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/working-with-models.html#dealing-with-relations)